# Difference between gzip -d and zcat

Tags: linux, compression, gzip

I was wondering what the difference is when decompressing using `gzip -d` and `zcat`.

Sometimes when I try `gzip -d` it says unknown suffix -- ignored. However, `zcat` works perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please do not use picture. Post text instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `zcat` equivalent using `gzip` is `gzip -dc`, and when used that way, it doesn’t care about the file extension. Both variants decompress their input and output the result to their standard output.

`gzip -d` on the other hand is intended to decompress a file, storing the uncompressed contents in another file. The output file’s name is calculated from the input’s, by removing its extension; files whose extension doesn’t match one of those handled by `gzip` are ignored. The documentation says that

> `gunzip` takes a list of files on its command line and replaces each file whose name ends with .gz, -gz, .z, -z, or _z (ignoring  case)  and  which  begins with the correct magic number with an uncompressed file without the original extension.
>          `gunzip` also recognizes the special extensions **.tgz** and **.taz** as shorthands for **.tar.gz** and **.tar.Z** respectively.

Files with no extension, or any other extension, are ignored, producing the message you see:

> unknown suffix — ignored